# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 23, saw 10

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to read data from IAM database with this line

```
data = pd.read_csv('words.csv' ,sep=' ',header=None)
```

but i got this error

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 23, saw 10
```

Because in line 23 of the last column, I have a string "M Ps" with a space and it is handled as separate columns.
[Click to see the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9VSr.png)

Any solutions?

Comment: Of course it's handled as separate columns. `sep=' '` means the space separates columns. How is it supposed to know that that space isn't a separator? If a column contains the separator, it needs to be quoted.

Comment: okay ,but there isn't other solution plz?

Comment: You'll have to write your own code to parse the lines. For instance, you can use `line.strip().split(' ', 9)` returns a maximum of 9 elements. Everything after that will be combined.